# How do I format a date in VBA with an abbreviated month?

Tags: vba, date

The code I am using is:

```
Format(now(), "MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

This code returns something like the following:

> March 10, 2013

How do I modify the date format code to output the abbreviated month as shown below?

> Mar 10, 2013

Comment: You need to set the clock on your computer to the right date.

Comment: I needed march to be shortened to just Mar. The solution is to use different format string, format(now(),"mmm dd,yyyy")

Comment: Format(now(), "MMM dd, yyyy") is the answer

Answer (score 18):

Use this:

```
Format(Now, "MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

More: [Format Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I'm using

```
Sheet1.Range("E2", "E3000").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
```

to format a column

So I guess

```
Sheet1.Range("E2", "E3000").NumberFormat = "MMM dd yyyy"
```

would do the trick  for you.

More: [NumberFormat function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx).