# Excel VBA Macro MsgBox auto converts number to Scientific notation, how do I stop this?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the current date into milliseconds so I can compare it to the AD "LastLogon" time stamp. The problem is that the current date automatically becomes scientific notation instead of the 18 digit number I am in need of. How do I force it to display all digits?

```
Dim currentDate
currentDate = Now * (8.64 * 10 ^ 11) + 109205
'MsgBox (DateAdd("d", -90, Now))
MsgBox (currentDate)
```

Comment: `I am trying to get the current date into milliseconds` Do you any any chance want to get the current time to show in miliseconds(with ms formatted as 6 digits)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 MsgBox( Format(currentDate, "#0"))
```

or other format you prefer

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim currentDate
currentDate = Now * (8.64 * 10 ^ 11) + 109205
'MsgBox (DateAdd("d", -90, Now))
MsgBox (Format(currentDate(), "MM dd, yyy"))
MsgBox (Format(Now(), "MM dd, yyy"))
```

Now() displays a date 
currentDate is an over flow.

[How to format date in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398759/how-to-format-date-in-vba)